# Como tirar a caixa de explicação do "valor" da função no VSCODE - Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

É uma caixa de mensagem que descreve o valor da função.
[[image: Imagem mostrando o 'popup' com a descrição da função]
<sup>clique para visualizar no tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TmAu.png)

Já mexi nas configurações, mas não tive sucesso
[[image: Imagem mostrando algumas configurações do VSCode como "editor.quickSuggestions"]
<sup>clique para visualizar no tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFChO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando o Visual Studio Code (VSCode) para programar em Python, pode estar se referindo à caixa de explicação que aparece ao digitar uma função e seus argumentos, conhecida como *"Signature Help"*.

Para desativar essa caixa de explicação, siga os seguintes passos:

1. Abra as configurações do Visual Studio Code pressionando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> ou indo em **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings**.
2. Na barra de pesquisa, procure por `python.languageServer` e selecione **Edit in settings.json**.
3. Adicione a seguinte linha ao arquivo:

   ```
   "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
   ```
4. Salve o arquivo e feche as configurações.
5. Reinicie o Visual Studio Code.

Com essa configuração, o *"Signature Help"* será desativado e você não verá mais a caixa de explicação dos argumentos das funções.

Comment: Fiz aqui e funcionou! Muito obrigado man!!!